# Which wallet provide lock-time feature?

Tags: locktime, sequence

I try to understand how the lock-time and sequence number work, but I got many different explanations, it is really confusing. I like to send a Bitcoin with lock-time to myself, but I don't know how to send contain a lock-time? I use Bitcoin-core right now.

or someone has an example transaction on blockchain.info, I want to see a transaction with lock-time and sequence number, but not 0xffffff。

thanks.